# Cron job not working

Tags: bash, scripts, cron, scrot-command

I have a script at `~/.sst/cmd.sh`. It takes screenshot and saves after creating a date heirarchy of folders. Here's Content:

```
#!/bin/sh
mkdir -p --mode=0755 /home/username/.sst/rslt/$(date +%Y)/$(date +%m)/$(date +%d)/$(date +%H)
scrot '/home/username/.sst/rslt/%Y/%m/%d/%H/%M%S.png'
```

Then I set it up as a cron to run every minute. Here's `$ crontab -l`

```
* * * * * /home/username/.sst/cmd.sh
```

The cron runs with no issue. I get the heirarchy of folders created, but there's no screenshot at the destination. What could be wrong with this?

When the script is manually run from CLI, it works and screenshot is generated.

I also tried putting the cron on root's crontab. No luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify the X DISPLAY.  You can do this in your script.

Modify your script to read:

```
#!/bin/sh
mkdir -p --mode=0755 /home/username/.sst/rslt/$(date +%Y)/$(date +%m)/$(date +%d)/$(date +%H)
export DISPLAY=:0 && scrot '/home/username/.sst/rslt/%Y/%m/%d/%H/%M%S.png'
```

The above display specification is assuming that screen ":0" is your active X DISPLAY `owned by you` (owned by the user running the crontab).

There are a number of ways you can specify the DISPLAY.  You could use as the third line:

```
env DISPLAY=:0 scrot '/home/username/.sst/rslt/%Y/%m/%d/%H/%M%S.png'
```

Or you could call your original script with one of many variations including:

```
* * * * * env DISPLAY=:0 /home/username/.sst/cmd.sh
```

You could replace `/home/username` with the variable `userhome` from the two lines:

```
username=`whoami`
userhome=`egrep "^$username:" /etc/passwd | awk -F: '{print $6}'`
```

Comment: Thanks. How can I get rid of `home/username/`? i used `~/.sst` . It works in mkdir command but not in scrot command.

Comment: @8thperson Look at the formatted lines appended to the answer.

Comment: Your script second line can be re-written: `mkdir -p --mode=0755 /home/username/.sst/rslt/$(date +%Y/%m/%d/%H)`. -> lesser load on your cpu.

Comment: My problem now is: while one user is locked, and another user is signed in, the screenshots taken by scrot are entirely black for both users.

Comment: Only one X display is going to be opened.  So if one user is longed on any other users will have a blank display.  The only display you should expect to see something from is the display that is actually active.  Are you saying that you are able to look at a display on your computer and see something other than a blank screen that doesn't show up in scrot?  If the X:0 is black or inactive that is what you will see in the captured image.  Scrot will only show you what is actually displayed on the active DISPLAY.